# How to test if alert/error message is displayed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uwp

I have a property on my VM with validation:

```
private string _test;
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
public string Test {
    get { return _test; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _test, value); }
}
```

Reference to ValidationAttribute: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

and this is my control from my View:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
        Text="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Errors[Test][0]}"
        Style="{StaticResource ViewErrorStyle}"/>
```

How can I unit test if the error message is shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MVC annotation directly on uwp. You can use prism validation. Please refer to follow link for more information.
https://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/User-input-validation-with-Prism-and-data-annotations-on-the-UWP.

Some Sample code in views:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="Email" 
             Header="Email"
             Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
             MaxLength="50"
             InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress" 
             AutomationProperties.IsRequiredForForm="True" />

    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Error_Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
               Foreground="Red"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

Some Sample code in view models:

```
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email address")]
    [Required]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _Email ?? string.Empty; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _Email, value);
            Error_Email = Errors[nameof(Email)].Count > 0 ? Errors[nameof(Email)][0] : string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string Error_Email
    {
        get { return _error_Email ?? string.Empty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _error_Email, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Im not asking about any issues on my validation , Im asking how can I unit test if in my test initialization I set the Test property to null or empty , how can i test if it shows the error message using assert

Comment: assert on 'Errors[Test][0]'. you may need UI automation tools for unit testing, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx